# Подстановка значения переменной внутри массива

Tags: javascript

Привет.

```
var arr = [2 + 3, 1 + 7];
alert(arr[0] + '::' + arr[1]) //5::8
var x = 100;
var arr2 = [2 + x, 4 + x];
alert(arr2[0] + '::' + arr2[1]) //102:104
```

Для меня стала открытием обработка переменных внутри масссива.

Пробую аналогичное для объекта

```
var obj = {
    foo: x
}
alert(obj.foo) //100
```

Где можно почитать более обширно по данной теме? Где еще можно использовать так переменные?

Comment: это основы js, почитайте основы js!

Comment: видимо пропустил эти основы

Comment: в CoffeeScript пошли дальше:

    x = 'value'
    y = 'another value'
    obj = {x,y}  

что эквивалентно:

    var obj, x, y;
    x = 'value';
    y = 'another value';
    obj = {
      x: x,
      y: y
    };

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Где еще можно использовать так переменные?

немного расскажу, где их можно будет использовать в недалёком будущем(мало ли, может кто не в курсе)

##### Destructuring assignment:

```
var a = 1, b = 2;
[a, b] = [b, a];
// или например так:
var { x:a, y:b } = { x:1, y:2 };
```

можно свапнуть значения, где это полезно? пример из исходников [backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-40):

```
set: function(key, value, options) {
    var attrs, attr, val;
if (_.isObject(key) || key == null) {
    attrs = key;
    options = value;
} else {
    attrs = {};
    attrs[key] = value;
}
```

тело `if` можно с лёгкостью будет заменить на:

```
[attrs, options] = [key, value]
```

##### Generator Expressions:

```
[ i for ( i in [5,6,7,8,9] ) ] // [0,1,2,3,4]
[ i for each ( i in [5,6,7,8,9] ) ] // [5,6,7,8,9]
[ i for each ( i in [5,6,7,8,9] ) if (i % 2 != 0)] // [5,7,9]
```

опять же сфер применения достаточно

##### Optional named function arguments

```
function foo({ name:name, project:project}) {

    console.log(project);
    console.log(name);
}

foo({ name:'soubok', project:'jslibs' });
foo({ project:'jslibs', name:'soubok'});
```

подробнее:

- [Новое в JavaScript 1.7](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Новое_в_JavaScript_1.7)
- [New in JavaScript 1.8](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/1.8)
- [JavaScript language advanced Tips & Tricks](http://code.google.com/p/jslibs/wiki/JavascriptTips)